# Run .net core web api in local network

Tags: .net-core, kestrel

I want to develop and test .net core web api that is running in 192.168.x.x address range instead of 127.0.0.1

In the end i want to get results from that api but running from browser on my mobile (which is connected to same wi-fi network)

Tried to modify kestrel to run:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseUrls("http://192.168.0.10:5000")
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

But it didn't work, error: 
Cannot assign requested address... at at System.Net.Sockets.Socket

Answer (score 2):

One simple workaround would be changing your `launchSettings.json` (if working with VisualStudio) or launch params to listen to URLs `http://0.0.0.0:5000` and `https://0.0.0.0:5001`.

Using those URLs will bind kestrel to all available IP addresses on your local machine.

Also, depending on how you query your API, you might have to configure CORS. On a developement environment I usually add the following line to `Startup.Configure`:

```cs
app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
```

Comment: i've already configured cors as you did.

your solution works but only from my desktop computer. is there a way to try it from mobile that is on the same network (meaning connected to same router)

Comment: Being on the same router doesnt necessarly means they're on the same network, can you ping your cellphone's IP from your computer?

Some routers also have isolation set in place for isolate devices on the Wifi from each other. If I recall correctly that technology is called `AP Isolation`.

From https://www.techwalla.com/articles/what-is-ap-isolation their definition for AP Isolation is: "AP isolation is a technique for preventing mobile devices connected to an AP from communicating directly with each other"

Comment: Changing `launchsettings.json` to `0.0.0.0` is a total pain in the ass because it prevents your browser opening when you hit F5.